# Micronaut & sdl-odata-framework

Tags: java, odata, micronaut

I am trying to replace Spring with Micronaut in this odata example: 
https://github.com/sdl/odata-example but the problem I'm facing at this time is that when you add support for spring annotations the project still can't autowire ODataService (the default implementation of this interface is written is Scala). So my question is: Is there a way for Micronaut to use libraries that are created in Scala?

Comment: In general, if you want to use scala code from java, you need to provide java interfaces and scala implementation of them.

Comment: thanks for a quick response. The sdl-odata has OdataService interface writen in java  and implementation is in scala and it works in spring project, but in micronaut project it's like it doesn't even see that scala implementation exists. With micronaut you can write projects in Java, Kotlin and Groovy, I was just wondering if there is a way to use a dependency that has implementation of interfaces in scala or if that's impossible at the moment

Comment: Micronaut doesn't support our DI annotations on Scala instances.  You could easily write a Micronaut factory in Groovy, Java or Kotlin (the languages which are supported) and that factory can create instances of classes written in any JVM language, Scala included.